# How to select all records with the same invoice number at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have table `Purchased_Order_Log`. I want to select all the records with the same invoice number at once.

My query that I tried

```
Select distinct(Invoice_no),
    Date_of_Purchase, Item_Code, Item_Name,
    Description, Supplier_Name, Company_Name, 
    Quantity, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Selling_Price,   
    Discount, Paid_Amount, Remaining, Sub_Total, Total,
    Updated_Date 
From 
    Purchase_Order_Log  
Order By 
    Invoice_no
```

The query returns this result:

```
Invoice No.      Item_Name          Quantity
---------------------------------------------
1001             Mackbook           1
1001             Keyboard           2
1001             Mouse              1

1002             Laptop Hp          1
1002             Dell               1

1003             PS4                1
1003             Xbox               1

1004             Wireless Mouse     5
```

I want the result look like this:

```
Invoice No.      Item_Name          Quantity
--------------------------------------------
1001             Mackbook           1
1002             Laptop Hp          1
1003             PS4                1
1004             Wireless Mouse     5
```

I tried many queries but i am unable to do it.

Working query as @user8834780 answered:

```
Select 
    Invoice_no, Date_of_Purchase, 
    Item_Code, Item_Name, Description,
    Supplier_Name, Company_Name, 
    Quantity, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Selling_Price, 
    Discount, Paid_Amount, Remaining, Sub_Total, Total, Updated_Date --spell out the rows you need
From
    (Select 
         Invoice_no, Date_of_Purchase, Item_Code, Item_Name, Description,
         Supplier_Name, Company_Name, Quantity, Unit_Price, Total_Price,
         Selling_Price, Discount, Paid_Amount, Remaining,
         Sub_Total, Total, Updated_Date, --spell out the rows you need
         row_number() over(partition by invoice_no order by invoice_no) as rown
     From 
         Purchase_Order_Log) as a
Where 
    rown = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to show where you need to spell out the rows you need. x should be same in query and subquery:

```
select x --spell out the rows you need
from
(
select x, --spell out the rows you need
row_number() over(partition by invoice_no order by invoice_no) as rown
from Purchased_Order_Log
) as a
where rown=1
```

`row_number over()` is something that's called a Window Function. As per your expected output, what row number does here is group all records of invoice_no, order them (in this case by a proxy but you can choose a date column instead to order it by recency, ie. `order by date desc`), and only take the first record.
You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

Comment: btw i didn't understand this query but i run this and got an error
`Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
The function 'row_number' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.`

Comment: @Usama try now. Note that you can put whatever you want to order by, in order by clause inside over(). I provided detail about the function too

Comment: Query is Working Correctly But I want to remove this rown column at the end of my result?

Comment: @Usama then explicitly select the columns you want instead of select a.*. ie. select invoice_no, item_name, quantity, etc.

Comment: Tried but got an error. This query is working i just want to remove the rown column `select a.*
from
(
select *,
row_number() over(partition by Invoice_no order by Invoice_no desc) as rown
from Purchase_Order_Log
) as a
where rown=1` kindly also explain what does a.* means

Comment: @Usama you didn't explicitly select the columns as you can see by the select * statement both in the subquery and the main query. Just don't use select * and instead explicitly state the columns you want, ie.  select invoice_no, item_name, quantity, etc. See my edited solution

Comment: Everything Works Perfectly :)

Comment: @Usama great! I suggest you read about it so you can use the varierty of other super helpful window functions

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use group by?

You can give this a try:

```
Select  *  
From Purchase_Order_Log 
group by Invoice_no
```

Comment: He only wants to keep the first row for each invoice

Comment: I already tried group by but got an error `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Purchase_Order_Log.Invoice_no' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Usama I tried the query in it works well. Can you provide more details regarding the error?

Comment: @user8834780 yes, it keeps the first row for each invoice

Comment: @Miggy your query A) will throw an error because you are grouping 1 column out of many unaggregated columns. Either all or none should be grouped if no aggregate functions are present B) returns all rows for invoice_id, not only the first one. This type of grouping may be possible in MySQL- but not possible in SQL Server